# How to escape from apostrophe character in C# while parsing the HTML

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing

I searched this problem on the site, what I found, did not solve my problem.
While I am parsing the HTML, I basically could not escape from the single quote character which is

> '

Here is my partial code:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string page = web.DownloadString(URL);
string publications = "<h3 class=\"gs_rt\"><a href=\"(.*?)\" onmousedown=\"return scife_clk(this.href,'','res','(.*?)')\">(.*?)</a></h3>";
string authors = "<div class=\"gs_a\">(.*?)</div";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(page, publications))
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);
    listBox1.Items.Add(match.Groups[3].Value);
}
```

Edit:

Here is the sites link:

http://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=9865132894872604322

What I want to have is the Title of the Publication. It is the third `(.*?)` in `publications`.

Edit2: I did not receive anything for a return. I want to have `User profiles for personalized information access` kind of Titles. While the HTML code has type of punctuations like that`"`,I use `/"`. What I am asking is, what should I do for this `'` character.

Comment: What do you mean by "could not escape from"? Can you give sample input, expected output and actual output? Are you sure you want to do HTML parsing yourself rather than using an existing library?

Comment: I edited my question. Please check it out.

Comment: That hasn't given us a sample input string, expected output and actual output. (I'm not sure whether it breaches Google Scholar's terms of service, either...)

Comment: You might do much better than Regex with some proper language parsers. If the HTML in question is proper XML document (though you cannot count on it if you have to parse any arbitrary page) you can use XML parsing solutions from .NET. If it is not, there are multiple solutions for it: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to name one.

Comment: I am working on same structured pages. So, I have used this approximation and I had not failed until this time.

Answer (score 1):

This line taken from your code:

```
string publications = "<h3 class=\"gs_rt\"><a href=\"(.*?)\" onmousedown=\"return scife_clk(this.href,'','res','(.*?)')\">(.*?)</a></h3>";
```

...when printed to a `textBox` returns:

```
<h3 class="gs_rt"><a href="(.*?)" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'','res','(.*?)')">(.*?)</a></h3>
```

...which as far as I can see includes all single quotes in the original string.

You can manipulate the single quote by—surprise surprise—escaping it using a backslash: `\'` (link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)).

Random example:

```
char singleQuote = '\'';
publications = publications.Replace(singleQuote, 'A');
```

...will replace all `'` to (random choice) `A`:

```
<h3 class="gs_rt"><a href="(.*?)" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,AA,AresA,A(.*?)A)">(.*?)</a></h3>
```

It's still not clear what you're trying to accomplish though. If this does not answer your question, please update your post as per the comments on your original post.